# Перестал работать модуль OS SYSTEM

Tags: python, ос

У меня внезапно перестал работать модуль OS. Внезапно потому что сам я ничего намерено не делал для этого, возможно изменения внесли какие то программы.
Сначала перестал работать скрипт питона использующий os system, при этом он уже не был питоновским, я перевел его в exe файл.
Пошел проверить в питоне, там модуль тоже не срабатывал, выдавая иероглифы в ошибке.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Тогда запустил через командную строку, там тоже не сработало, тогда я понял что это не проблема питона, а системная.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Не знаю как это исправлять и в какую сторону копать. Можно ли этот модуль включить обратно вручную?
Винда 7

Comment: скорее всего файл `shutdown.exe` был поврежден/удален. восстановите его

Answer (score 2):

Либо поврежден или удален `shutdown.exe`, либо Вы используете урезанную сборку `Windows` вообше без `shutdown.exe`. Можете проверить, ввести просто в командной строке:

```
shutdown -s -t 30
```

Если не работает, значит 100% проблема в `shutdown.exe` Еще попробуйте проверить системные файлы и при возможности восстановить их с помощью команды:

```
sfc /scannow
```

Проверьте, есть ли файл `shutdown.exe` в папке:

```
C:\Windows\system32 (для 32-битного Windows)
C:\Windows\SysWOW64 (для 64-битного Windows)
```

Если файла нет, то попробуйте скачать образ такой же редакции и архитектуры `Windows 7`, как у Вас и скопируйте файл оттуда.
Надеюсь, чем-то помог.

Comment: у меня не работает весь модуль os а не только шутдаун. а по поводу проверить shutdown -s -t 30 я и так его проверил в посте, это есть на скрине, зачем мне советовать это

Answer (score 0):

Строка не ищет нужные программы по пути `«%windir%\system32».`

Данная проблема скорее всего заключается в системной переменной PATH, она может быть изменена. И для стандартной работы штатных программ надо восстановить в ней начальные значения.

Чтобы исправить эту ошибку, открываем **«Панель управления» — «Система»**, переходим на вкладку **«Дополнительно»**, там нажимаем кнопку **«Переменные среды»**. В открывшемся окне в разделе **«Системные переменные»** находим переменную **«Path»**.

Затем либо двойным щелчком мыши вызываем окно «Изменение системной переменной», либо выделяем эту переменную и нажимаем на кнопку «Изменить», находящуюся под ней. Значение переменной должно быть следующим:

`%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem`

Если выглядит не так, изменяем.

**Источник:** [тык](https://tweakov.net/v-komandnoj-stroke-windows-ne-rabotayut-standartnye-komandy.html)